# eventmachine on debian fails install via rubygems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, debian, diskspace

this has been killing me for the last 5 hours. I don't seem to be able to get eventmachine running on my debian box.

here this output:

```
$ gem install thin
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing thin:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/eventhub/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... yes
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking for epoll_create() in sys/epoll.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling kb.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from project.h:149,
                 from kb.cpp:20:
binder.h:35: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:150,
                 from kb.cpp:20:
em.h:84: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:85: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:86: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:88: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:89: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:90: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:91: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:116: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:125: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:154,
                 from kb.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:46: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:48: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:50: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:66: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:67: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:68: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:154,
                 from kb.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:103: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:108: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
compiling rubymain.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from project.h:149,
                 from rubymain.cpp:20:
binder.h:35: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:150,
                 from rubymain.cpp:20:
em.h:84: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:85: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:86: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:88: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:89: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:90: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:91: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:116: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:125: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:154,
                 from rubymain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:46: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:48: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:50: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:66: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:67: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:68: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:154,
                 from rubymain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:103: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:108: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
compiling ssl.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from project.h:149,
                 from ssl.cpp:23:
binder.h:35: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:150,
                 from ssl.cpp:23:
em.h:84: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:85: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:86: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:88: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:89: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:90: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:91: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:116: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:125: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:154,
                 from ssl.cpp:23:
eventmachine.h:46: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:48: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:50: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:66: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:67: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:68: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:154,
                 from ssl.cpp:23:
eventmachine.h:103: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:108: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
compiling cmain.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from project.h:149,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
binder.h:35: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:150,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
em.h:84: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:85: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:86: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:88: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:89: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:90: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:91: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:116: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:125: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:154,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:46: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:48: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:50: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:66: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:67: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:68: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:154,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:103: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:108: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:96: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:107: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:117: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:127: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:269: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:279: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:289: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:299: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:309: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:329: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:678: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
compiling em.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from project.h:149,
                 from em.cpp:23:
binder.h:35: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:150,
                 from em.cpp:23:
em.h:84: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:85: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:86: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:88: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:89: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:90: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:91: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:116: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:125: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:154,
                 from em.cpp:23:
eventmachine.h:46: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:48: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:50: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:66: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:67: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:68: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:154,
                 from em.cpp:23:
eventmachine.h:103: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:108: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.cpp: In member function 'bool EventMachine_t::_RunEpollOnce()':
em.cpp:578: warning: 'int rb_thread_select(int, fd_set*, fd_set*, fd_set*, timeval*)' is deprecated (declared at /home/eventhub/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:379)
em.cpp:578: warning: 'int rb_thread_select(int, fd_set*, fd_set*, fd_set*, timeval*)' is deprecated (declared at /home/eventhub/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:379)
em.cpp: In member function 'bool EventMachine_t::_RunSelectOnce()':
em.cpp:974: warning: 'int rb_thread_select(int, fd_set*, fd_set*, fd_set*, timeval*)' is deprecated (declared at /home/eventhub/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:379)
em.cpp:974: warning: 'int rb_thread_select(int, fd_set*, fd_set*, fd_set*, timeval*)' is deprecated (declared at /home/eventhub/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:379)
em.cpp: At global scope:
em.cpp:1057: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.cpp:1079: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.cpp:1265: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.cpp:1338: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.cpp:1510: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.cpp:1593: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.cpp:1856: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.cpp:1982: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.cpp:2046: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.cpp:2070: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.cpp:2142: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.cpp:2361: fatal error: error writing to /tmp/ccdlOK0T.s: No space left on device
compilation terminated.
make: *** [em.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/eventhub/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/eventmachine-1.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/eventhub/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/eventmachine-1.0.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

Any thoughts? I read a lot of different ways to solve this issue, but none of them worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think by looking the log you provide that you have a lack of disk space.

```
em.cpp:2361: fatal error: error writing to /tmp/ccdlOK0T.s: No space left on device
compilation terminated.
make: *** [em.o] Error 1
```

Try a `df` on commandline to check available space on your partition '/'